# Is a compiled python program a derivative of Python

Tags: python, licensing

Is a "compiled" python program (i.e. *.pyc file created by CPython) a derivative product of CPython? In other words, does one need to comply the [Python license](http://docs.python.org/license.html) in all the programs he or she writes?

Disclaimer: I know that the answers here do not qualify as legal consultation.

Comment: This site isn't ideal for legal questions about software licenses. If you want legal advice, the surest thing is to consult a lawyer. That said, kindall's answer reflects my understanding of how everyone sees this in practice. People have distributed Python code under all sorts of licenses, with and without source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, from a licensing standpoint "derivative" applies to a modified version of the Python interpreter or its standard libraries, not to programs you write that run on the interpreter. It doesn't matter whether your programs are expressed as plain text or as compiled bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison: [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) is distributed under a modified version of the GPL because the code it generates *does* use some of the code distributed with bison.

Under a strict interpretation of the standard GPL all resulting code *would* be derivative. [Since the intent was to allow people to use the output of these tools for any purpose the license had to be modified.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Conditions.html)